# Convert .mov to base64 encoded string IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, base64, media, nsdata

I am trying to convert media files in my IOS app to base 64 encoded strings. When I convert an image, I successfully see the encoded string on the console.

```
 NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo" ofType:@"jpg"]];
NSString *base64Encoded = [videoData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64Encoded);
```

But when I try to give a .mov file, it does not print anything.

```
 NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mov"]];
```

Can someone please tell me what is that I am doing wrong? Or how can I convert .mov file to base64 encoded string?

Thanks

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198152/large-base64-uploads-in-ios

Comment: I used this  NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:currentItemImagePath];
       base64Encoded = [videoData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
and my problem got solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link and you will be able to find the solution.

http://cocoadev.com/BaseSixtyFour

Comment: I am trying to achieve this by using the ion NSData methods. http://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#base64 and not use any 3rd party library/classes. Is it possible to achieve a solution to my problem using the nsdata methods?

Comment: Have you check before encoding the data, is there any data in the object "videoData"